# Ruby neo4j-core mass processing data

Tags: ruby, neo4j, cypher

Has anyone used Ruby [neo4j-core](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core) to mass process data? Specifically, I am looking at taking in about 500k lines from a relational database and insert them via something like:

```
Neo4j::Session.current.transaction.query
             .merge(m: { Person: { token: person_token} })
             .merge(i: { IpAddress: { address: ip, country: country,
                                      city: city, state: state } })
             .merge(a: { UserToken: { token: token } })
             .merge(r: { Referrer: { url: referrer } })
             .merge(c: { Country: { name: country } })
             .break # This will make sure the query is not reordered
             .create_unique("m-[:ACCESSED_FROM]->i")
             .create_unique("m-[:ACCESSED_FROM]->a")
             .create_unique("m-[:ACCESSED_FROM]->r")
             .create_unique("a-[:ACCESSED_FROM]->i")
             .create_unique("a-[:ACCESSED_FROM]->r")
             .create_unique("i-[:IN]->c")
             .exec
```

However doing this locally it takes hours on hundreds of thousands of events. So far, I have attempted the folloiwng:

- Wrapping Neo4j::Connection in a ConnectionPool and multi-threading it - I did not see much speed improvements here.
- Doing `tx = Neo4j::Transaction.new` and `tx.close` every 1000 events processed - looking at a TCP dump, I am not sure this actually does what I expected. It does the exact same requests, with the same frequency, but just has a different response.

With Neo4j::Transaction I see a POST every time the `.query(...).exec` is called:

- Request: `{"statements":[{"statement":"MERGE (m:`Person`{token: {m_Person_token}}) ...{"m_Person_token":"AAA"...,"resultDataContents":["row","REST"]}]}`
- Response: `{"commit":"http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/868/commit","results":[{"columns":[],"data":[]}],"transaction":{"expires":"Tue, 10 May 2016 23:19:25 +0000"},"errors":[]}`

With Non-Neo4j::Transactions I see the same POST frequency, but this data:

- Request: `{"query":"MERGE (m:`Person`{token: {m_Person_token}}) ... {"m_Person_token":"AAA"..."c_Country_name":"United States"}}`
- Response: `{"columns" : [ ], "data" : [ ]}`

(Not sure if that is intended behavior, but it looks like less data is transmitted via the Non-Neo4j::Transaction technique - highly possibly I am doing something incorrectly)

Some other ideas I had:
* Post process into a CSV, SCP up and then use the `neo4j-import` command line utility (although, that seems kinda hacky).
* Combine both of the techniques I tried above.

Has anyone else run into this / have other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!

So you're absolutely right.  With `neo4j-core` you can only send one query at a time.  With transactions all you're really getting is the ability to rollback.  Neo4j does have a nice HTTP JSON API for transactions which allows you to send multiple Cypher requests in the same HTTP request, but `neo4j-core` doesn't currently support that (I'm working on a refactor for the next major version which will allow this).  So there are a number of options:

- You can submit your requests via raw HTTP JSON to the APIs.  If you still want to use the `Query` API you can use the `to_cypher` and `merge_params` methods to get the cypher and params for that (`merge_params` is a private method currently, so you'd need to `send(:merge_params)`)
- You can load via CSV as you said.  You can either

  - use the `neo4j-import` command which allows you to import *very* fast but requires you to put your CSV in a specific format, requires that you be creating a DB from scratch, and requires that you create indexes/constraints after the fact
  - use the `LOAD CSV` command which isn't as fast, but is still pretty fast.
- You can use the [`neo4apis`](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis) gem to build a DSL to import your data.  The gem will create Cypher queries under the covers and will batch them for performance.  See examples of the gem in use via [`neo4apis-twitter`](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis-twitter) and [`neo4apis-github`](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis-github)
- If you are a bit more adventurous, you can use the new Cypher API in `neo4j-core` via the [`new_cypher_api`](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/tree/new_cypher_api) branch on the GitHub repo.  The `README` in that branch has some documentation on the API, but also feel free to drop by our [Gitter chat room](https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j) if you have questions on this or anything else.

If you're implementing a solution which is going to make queries like above where you have multiple `MERGE` clauses, you'll probably want to profile your queries to make sure that you are [avoiding the eager](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/) (that post is a bit old and newer versions of Neo4j have alleviated some of the need for care, but you can still look for `Eager` in your `PROFILE`)

Also worth a look: Max De Marzi's post on [Scaling Cypher Writes](https://maxdemarzi.com/2016/02/18/scaling-cypher-writes/)